# Remove active class "classList.remove" in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have javascript code that adds class to the div `panel-s-c-3` on mouseover. So if I hover the item, it will add class `active-s-c-cardexp`. I need to remove that class after I leave the item area. This is what I have. Will be happy for any suggestions..

```
const panels2 = document.querySelectorAll(".panel-s-c-3");

panels2.forEach((panel2) => {
    panel2.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        removeActiveclasses2();
        panel2.classList.add("active-s-c-cardexp");
    });
});

function removeActiveclasses2() {
    panels2.forEach((panel2) => {
        panel2.classList.remove("active-s-c-cardexp");
    });
}
```

Comment: why you do not using css  `panel-s-c-3:hover` then define style of active element

Comment: That's correct question.. It's an expand card, and I need it to work in that way, otherwise of course I use hover..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove active class on mouseleave event as below:

```
panel2.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  panel2.classList.add("active-s-c-cardexp");
});

panel2.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  removeActiveclasses2();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using mouseenter to add class `active-s-c-cardexp` and then mouseleave to remove the class